# c# Azure.AI.OpenAI with errors at start

Tags: c#, azure, azure-openai

I am trying to follow the Microsoft how to (in its c# way):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Creating the code with the template as instructions indicate:
`dotnet new console -n azure-openai-quickstart`

After I have added requested package:
`dotnet add package Azure.AI.OpenAI --prerelease`
It added the package `Azure.AI.OpenAI 1.0.0-beta.12`

Open code with my Visual Studio and I have several errors.
Starting with `ChatMessage` and following with `SearchKey` property inside `AzureCognitiveSearchChatExtensionConfiguration` class:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve this and follow with the How-to?

Why Microsoft leave an incorrect and not functional how-to to "help" people to start with a technology?

This is the `.csproj` file as requested in comments:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>azure_openai_quickstart</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.AI.OpenAI" Version="1.0.0-beta.12" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you please share your `.csproj` file

Comment: Your posted code needs to be in a class and a namespace.  At bottom of you link it says "I ran into issue when running code sample".  I would create a new console project.  Then place using statement at top of module.  Put rest of code into Main.

Comment: Please do not paste the screenshot of the code. Instead, paste the code itself in the question.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried to use it on a class in the old-style way.  The problem is the same. If you see the example: `Without response streaming` it is exactly as my example. :-)  I have fill the form in the button: `I ran into issue....`  No answer for the moment.

Comment: @GauravMantri You can get the complete code using the command `dotnet new console -n azure-openai-quickstart` and this one also: `dotnet add package Azure.AI.OpenAI --prerelease` 
It is a template from microsoft.  If you open it, you don't have errors on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with version `1.0.0-beta.12` of `Azure.AI.OpenAI` Nuget package. The code in the sample is compatible with version `1.0.0-beta.8` and there have been many changes (including breaking ones) between these 2 versions. For more details, please see the [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.AI.OpenAI_1.0.0-beta.12/sdk/openai/Azure.AI.OpenAI/CHANGELOG.md).

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Downgrade to version `1.0.0-beta.8`. You would need to uninstall the current version and install `1.0.0-beta.8` using `dotnet add package Azure.AI.OpenAI --version 1.0.0-beta.8`. Though I would not recommend doing it.
2. Change the code so that it is compatible with version `1.0.0-beta.12`.

I made some changes in the code so that at least it compiles (haven't tried to run it though). Here's the code that compiles:

```
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;
using System.Text.Json;
using static System.Environment;

string azureOpenAIEndpoint = GetEnvironmentVariable("AOAIEndpoint");
string azureOpenAIKey = GetEnvironmentVariable("AOAIKey");
string searchEndpoint = GetEnvironmentVariable("SearchEndpoint");
string searchKey = GetEnvironmentVariable("SearchKey");
string searchIndex = GetEnvironmentVariable("SearchIndex");
string deploymentName = GetEnvironmentVariable("AOAIDeploymentId");

var client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri(azureOpenAIEndpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(azureOpenAIKey));

var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
{
    Messages =
    {
        new ChatRequestUserMessage("What are the differences between Azure Machine Learning and Azure AI services?"),
    },
    AzureExtensionsOptions = new AzureChatExtensionsOptions()
    {
        Extensions =
        {
            new AzureCognitiveSearchChatExtensionConfiguration()
            {
                SearchEndpoint = new Uri(searchEndpoint),
                Key = searchKey,
                IndexName = searchIndex,
            },
        }
    },
    DeploymentName = deploymentName
};

Response<ChatCompletions> response = client.GetChatCompletions(chatCompletionsOptions);

ChatResponseMessage responseMessage = response.Value.Choices[0].Message;

Console.WriteLine($"Message from {responseMessage.Role}:");
Console.WriteLine("===");
Console.WriteLine(responseMessage.Content);
Console.WriteLine("===");

Console.WriteLine($"Context information (e.g. citations) from chat extensions:");
Console.WriteLine("===");
foreach (ChatResponseMessage contextMessage in responseMessage.AzureExtensionsContext.Messages)
{
    string contextContent = contextMessage.Content;
    try
    {
        var contextMessageJson = JsonDocument.Parse(contextMessage.Content);
        contextContent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(contextMessageJson, new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            WriteIndented = true,
        });
    }
    catch (JsonException)
    {}
    Console.WriteLine($"{contextMessage.Role}: {contextContent}");
}
Console.WriteLine("===");
```

BTW, I also opened an issue on GitHub regarding this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/118601.

Comment: Yes, it compiles now.  Thank you.
It does not run at all, but it is a problem for another search or another questions.
:-)